# Median of $\sin(289^\circ),$ $\sin(145^\circ),$ $\sin(365^\circ),$ $\cos(72^\circ),$ and $\frac 12$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

**Note**: This question was taken from the contest [Math Day at the Beach $2016$](http://web.csulb.edu/depts/math/pdfs/mathday/MDB16Qs.pdf), which does not allow the use of calculators/computing systems.

> What is the median of $\sin(289^\circ),$ $\sin(145^\circ),$ $\sin(365^\circ),$ $\cos(72^\circ),$ and $\frac 12?$

I would convert them to $-\sin(109^\circ),$ $\sin(145^\circ),$ $\sin(5^\circ),$ $\cos(72^\circ),$ and $\frac 12$. What would be the best way to then approximate these values?

Comment: I thin the first on is $-\sin(71)$.

Comment: Please, put the degree signs on the arguments.  It is much easier to deal with $\sin(289^\circ)$ than $\sin(289$ radians)$  The original paper had it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Note that $\frac 12=\sin 30^\circ$ and that $\sin$ is increasing from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.  You should be able to subtract $180^\circ$ or $90^\circ$ to get all the angles into the first quadrant, sometimes with minus signs attached.  Then you are done.

Comment: What happens when I subtract 90?

Comment: If you subtract 90 you change to cosine.  If you subtract from 90 you get back to sine.  These are identities that are useful to know.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Is there a place where I can find a list of all these identities?

Comment: The[re are many tables.  One is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).  Each one has to decide which ones are common enough to list and which to leave out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50869/discussion-between-suomynona-and-ross-millikan).